# awsebcli: installed EB CLI with python 3.9 version via homebrew. Python 3.7 is used in project - potential problems?

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, homebrew, aws-cli

I need to run AWS Elastic Beanstalk for deploying django (Django==3.1.5) project.
So I've recently installed EB CLI (macOS) 3.19, which by default installed with Python 3.9.1 via Homebrew.

But I have python 3.7 installed and using it for my project's configuration:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.6
```

Would it cause any problem in further deploy?
Should I delete it and install via pip?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't be a problem. However safest would be to keep the versions same.